# Extract feature and not 3 band RGB (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, raster, wms, wfs

I am trying to extract the data from the following WFS:

https://globalatlas2.masdar.ac.ae/geoserver/gwa/wfs

I am interested in the layer "Global Wind Atlas wind speed mean 1km at 100m height DTU 2015". I am using QGIS, version 2.18.15.

When I right click and choose "Save as" for the layer I can download it. However, the issue I am having is that it downloads a 3-band raster of pixel RGB values rather than the underlying feature. This is shown in the attached image using the "Identify Features" tool: the top image is the data that I want, from the WFS, but the bottom is actually what is saved.

How do I save the feature as it is defined in the WFS, and not the Pixel RGB values? I tried both the "Raw Data" and the "Rendered Image" save modes but both produced the same result.

Comment: I don't understand. There are no WFS layers in this service https://globalatlas2.masdar.ac.ae/geoserver/gwa/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=getcapabilities. I guess that you used that URL for adding a WMS service and that doesn not deliver any vector data. You cannot download vectors from that service because it is not configured to serve vector data.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. Yep I did add it as a WMS service, but when I do I can see a folder in there called "Global wind atlas wfs", which is where I loaded the layer from. But despite the name is this also a WMS service? Sorry if it is a stupid question

Comment: For some reason I do not see such layer name or title but if you access a WMS service all the layers are WMS layers.

Comment: There is a WFS available from the provider, but none in the gws namespace:  https://globalatlas2.masdar.ac.ae/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `https://globalatlas2.masdar.ac.ae/geoserver/gwa/wfs?request=getcapabilities` returns a complete and correct response it does not contain any layers so I guess they don't want (anonymouse) people to play with thier data.

However, they do provide a WCS endpoint at `https://globalatlas2.masdar.ac.ae/geoserver/gwa/wcs?request=getcapabilities` which does provide layers. This will allow you to download the actual data raster rather than a picture of it as the WMS allows you to do.